# Assign full path of the file to a variable Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, path

I am creating a script for windows.
Idea is to schedule it to a daily basis using Task Manager.
The diffuculty is that i want to make this script portable, so whenever someone runs it on thiers computer, it should work . I need to make path not "hard coded", so the file could be found wherever it was downloaded.

```
Write-Host "Windows1"


$pathname= get-childitem "C:\Users\" -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name  -Like "ScheduledUpdateAndScan.ps1"} 

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument $pathname

$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 11am

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Windows1" -Description "Windows1 daily scan routine and check for updates"
```

But $pathname won't take the full path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diotm.png)

It only takes the actual name of the file
Please, help me if you can

Comment: $fullname1= get-childitem "C:\Users\" -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name  -Like "ScheduledUpdateAndScan*"} 
Write-Host $fullname1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not passed it the full path.

```
$pathname= get-childitem "C:\Users\" -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name  -Like "ScheduledUpdateAndScan.ps1"}
```

The variable `$pathname` contain a fileinfo object. It has many properties, one of those is call `FullName`. You should specify this in your command.

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument $pathname.FullName
```

Comment: I highly recommend reading and living this document [Tips on writing cross platform PowerShell](https://powershell.org/2019/02/tips-for-writing-cross-platform-powershell-code/)